# Changing the unknown attributes from a parent class for a child class

Tags: python, oop, pygame

I want to create a child class Cell with parent Class pygame.Rect but I cannot get the attribute top of the instance of the class Cell to change and it's just set to zero.
My Code is:

```
import pygame

light = pygame.Color('#D3D3D3')
dark = pygame.Color('#222222')

class Cell(pygame.Rect):
    def __init__(self, index, side):
        self.index = index
        self.side = side
        self.color = None       # Index is a tuple from (0, 0) to (2, 2)
        self.has_pawn = None

        # Setting coordinates
        for i in range(3):
            if index[1] == i:
                self.x = i*self.side
            if index[0] == i:
                self.y == (2-i)*self.side

        self.left = self.x
        self.top = self.y
        self.width = self.side
        self.height = self.side
        
        # self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)

        # Setting color
        sum = self.index[0] + self.index[1]
        if sum % 2 == 0:
            self.color = light
        if sum % 2 == 1:
            self.color = dark

        # Setting has_pawn
        if index[0] == 0 | index[1] == 2:
            self.has_pawn = True


b2 = Cell((1, 1), 5)
print(b2)
```

which gives the output:

```
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.1)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
<rect(5, 0, 5, 5)>
[Finished in 0.6s]
```

I hope someone can help me to get the attribute top of the Cell object to change.

Comment: You probably need to call `super().__init__()`, and pass in the appropriate parameters, so the parent class can initialize these properties.

Comment: I don't know what exactly is the "appropriate parameter" which is being used when I use the print function. So, I don't know if I used super().__init__(top) or something.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what the problem here is. Your `self.top` is 0, that is why `y` in `self.rect` value is 0 as well. In following loop,

```
# Setting coordinates
for i in range(3):
    if index[1] == i:
         self.x = i*self.side
    if index[0] == i:
         self.y == (2-i)*self.side
```

The value of `i` in the last iteration is `2`, which means in the last iteration this happens.

```
self.y == (2-2)*5 # 0*5 = 0
```

This results in `self.y` being set to 0, which in turn sets `self.top` to 0. So, it's not a surprise that you get the result you are getting.

If you do

```
super().__init__(pygame.Rect(10, 10, 10, 10))
```

The result printed is in fact  `<rect(10, 10, 10, 10)>`, so you should focus on fixing the loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code. You don't need the loop at all. `Cell` is a subclass of [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html). Compute the coordinate of the call:

```py
x = index[1] * self.side
y = (index[0]-2) * self.side
```

Use [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) to delegate to the constructor of `pygame.Rect`:

```py
super().__init__(x, y, self.side, self.side)
```

However, I don't know where `-2` comes from. You may want something like:

```py
x = offsetx + index[1] * self.side
y = offsety + index[0] * self.side
```

---

Class `Cell`:

```py
class Cell(pygame.Rect):
    def __init__(self, index, side):
        self.index = index
        self.side = side
        self.color = None       # Index is a tuple from (0, 0) to (2, 2)
        self.has_pawn = None

        x = index[1] * self.side
        y = (index[0]-2) * self.side
        super().__init__(x, y, self.side, self.side) 

        # Setting color
        sum = self.index[0] + self.index[1]
        if sum % 2 == 0:
            self.color = light
        if sum % 2 == 1:
            self.color = dark

        # Setting has_pawn
        if index[0] == 0 | index[1] == 2:
            self.has_pawn = True
```